# I'm trying to make a Instance at the mouse position but it doesn't work

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to make an instance at the mouse pos, but when it makes the instance, it's way off and is really far out from my mouse. How could I fix this? Here is my code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

// note
// note

public class attack : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform prefab;

    void Update()
    {
        Vector3 mousePos = Input.mousePosition;

        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
            Instantiate(prefab, mousePos, Quaternion.identity);


    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Input.mousePosition`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input-mousePosition.html) is in **screen pixel space**!

You most probably rather want to use [`Camera.ScreenToWorldSpace`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera.ScreenToWorldPoint.html)

```
public class attack : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform prefab;

    // you will need to figure this out
    public float desiredDistanceInFrontOfCamera;

    [SerializeFiel] private Camera _camera;

    private void Awake()
    {
        if(!_camera) _camera = Camera.main;
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            Vector3 mousePos = Input.mousePosition;
            mousePos.z = desiredDistanceInFrontOfCamera;
            Vector3 spawnPos = _camera.ScreenToWorldPoint(mousePos);
            Instantiate(prefab, spawnPos, Quaternion.identity);
        }
    }
}
```